# Can reportbug print only the list of bugs?

Tags: debian, deb, reportbug

I have been trying to get a list of bugs (with url and title) of installed packages, but I don't know if reportbug can shows the list bugs only.

This is my failed script:

```bsh
for package in $(dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' -W)
do
    reportbug -q -Q -u text $package
done
```

Comment: I found another command only show list bugs `querybts` but it waits to keypress.

Answer (score 0):

The script needs some love (need sed or awk to made a url of bug) but it is more or less:

```bsh
for package in $(dpkg-query -f '${Package}\n' -W)
do
    querybts -b -u text $package
done
```